# Function slice_sample gives error cannot take a sample larger than the population

Tags: r, dplyr, cell, sampling

I have a dataframe of cell barcodes (V1) and cell types (V2), I want to randomly sample 1000 of each cell type, unless there are less than 1000 total then all should be selected.

However slice_sample gives an error when encountering a cell type with less than 1000 rows. Despite the documentation stating "If n is greater than the number of rows in the group (or prop > 1), the result will be silently truncated to the group size." I don't want to sample with replacement. Am I misunderstanding the docs?

```
sample_cells <- as.data.frame(all_cells) %>% group_by(V2) %>% slice_sample(n=1000)
```

> Error in `slice_sample()`: ! Problem while computing indices. ℹ The
> error occurred in group 10: V2 = "PEC". Caused by error in
> `sample.int()`: ! cannot take a sample larger than the population when
> 'replace = FALSE' Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error
> occurred.

I expected to get 1000 rows for cell types where n>1000, and all the rows for cell types where n<1000.

dplyr version 1.0.10

Comment: What version of `dplyr` are you running?

Comment: I see the error too, yet the dplyr tests explicitly test that it should explicitly just allow it (https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/7eeea654ebe5279e1308a24fcac34f1b01c20912/tests/testthat/test-slice.R#L270). Hrmph.

Comment: Hi MrFlick, I am using version 1.0.10

Answer (score 0):

I agree this was a vexing problem in dplyr v1.0

The best solution is to update to dplyr v1.1.0, which implements slice_sample correctly. Here's an example:

```
birds <- tibble(Areas = c(rep("City", 40), rep("Beach", 60), rep("Forest",100)), Species = sample(c("Robin", "Seagul", "Owl"), size = 200, replace = T))

# Select 30 rows from each Area
birds %>% group_by(Areas) %>% slice_sample(n = 30) %>% .$Areas %>% table

# Select 50 rows from each Area. Because there are only 40 city birds, those are selected (this gave an error in earlier dplyr versions)
birds %>% group_by(Areas) %>% slice_sample(n = 50) %>% .$Areas %>% table
```

See also https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/6185

Answer (score -1):

To take a sample larger than your data, you need to define the parameter `replace = TRUE`, so:

```
slice_sample(replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: User specified "I don't want to sample with replacement," which would indeed be a bad idea when selecting single cells for gene expression analysis.